# Does the Windows Runtime provide ECDH?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I could not find any implementation of ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman algorithm) in the Windows runtime other than for working with certificates (Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.KeyAlgorithmNames). Is there really no equivalent of the ECDiffieHellmanCng class of .NET? What could we use instead to securely exchange keys?

Comment: No, it provides ECDSA.

Comment: As far as I know ECDSA can not be used to create (not exchange!) an identical private key using the public keys of two parties, can it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider) with anything from here [AsymmetricAlgorithmNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetricalgorithmnames)

Does not seem you have other options with WinRT except some 3rd party libs. You may consider alternatives, like openssl if exactly this algorithm is a must. [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2113595) some guys seem to succeed building openssl for WinRT platform. Hope this helps.

Comment: AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider does not provide an algorithm similar to ECDH. ECDH allows to create an identical private key using the public keys of two parties. This private key can be used to encrypt using a symmetrical algorithm. Sure one can use an asymmetric algorithm to exchange a key, but ECDH is more elegant since it creates the key and does not exchange it. Anyway: As it seems Windows 8 does not provide ECDH, for unknown reasons.

Comment: @JürgenBayer As for me the best way is to find some alternative like openssl.